# Does an Apex Class run linearly (procedurally?)?

Tags: apex, class, method

I am used to writing a run method in Java which specifies where the code runs. Outside of this nothing runs unless called.

In apex there I don't see a run method.

I'm guessing it starts at the top and works down, not running methods unless they're called within the primary code block?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a few different mechanisms that cause Apex code to be executed, so it depends on the context.

---

## Execute Anonymous/Triggers

Code is executed from top-to-bottom, with methods and so on being skipped over, but can be called from the main block:

```
void method1() {
  System.debug('method 1');
}
for(Integer i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  // we will output 'method 1' five times
  method1();
}
```

## Visualforce Controller/Component

Code starts from a particular constructor, while other methods are typically called by action attributes, such as `apex:commandLink` or `apex:actionFunction`.

## Lightning Controller/Webservice/RestResource

Any eligible method can be called directly. It does not go from top to bottom within the class, since you can call any method at any time within the rules for a particular interface.

## Batchable/Queueable/Scheduleable

The main method is called "execute" and is the entry point for execution.

## Future

The method runs directly without running a constructor or anything else.

## InvocableMethod

Called from a Flow.

---

I think you can see that there's a lot of ways you can run Apex Code. There's no "run" or "main" like there is in Java, but there are a ton of ways to run Apex code depending on the developer's intent.